# Refreshing Custom Listview with holder ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, listview

i`m doing a Custom listview with holder.it is perfectly loaded but while i refresh the data by pull down the application is force closing please help

```
  @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // View rowView = convertView;

            // String record = (String) getItem(position);

            // LayoutInflater inflater = Test_home.this.getLayoutInflater();

            LayoutInflater inflater = Test_home.this.getLayoutInflater();
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            if (convertView == null) {
                // LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
                // getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_list, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.claim_list_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.claim_list_layout);
                holder.claimnumb = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.claimnumb);
                holder.insuerdname = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.insuerdname);

                holder.claimaddress = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.claimaddress);
                holder.btn_start = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
            final ViewHolder holder1 = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            // holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            final Claim_list claim_option = claim_list_adaptor.get(position);

            holder1.claimnumb.setText(claim_option.getClaimNumber());
            holder1.insuerdname.setText(claim_option.getInsuredName());
            holder1.claimaddress.setText(claim_option.getPropertyAddress());

            // Tag Setting
            holder1.claimnumb.setTag(claim_option);
            holder1.insuerdname.setTag(claim_option);
            holder1.claimaddress.setTag(claim_option);
            holder1.claim_list_layout.setTag(claim_option);
            holder1.btn_start.setTag(claim_option);

            holder1.btn_start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (position == 0 && isoncreate) {
                isoncreate = false;
                holder1.claim_list_layout
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.claim_list_active);
                holder1.btn_start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                beanclass.setClaim_info_header("Claim: "
                        + claim_option.getClaimNumber() + " / "
                        + claim_option.getInsuredName());
                TV_claiminfo.setText(beanclass.getClaim_info_header());
            } else {
                holder1.claim_list_layout
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.claim_list_inactive);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
```

This is the error

```
01-02 11:15:39.989: W/dalvikvm(14670): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-02 11:15:40.062: W/System.err(14670): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.wbpro.da.Claim_list cannot be cast to com.wbpro.flood.Test_home$PullToRefreshListViewSampleAdapter$ViewHolder
01-02 11:15:40.085: W/System.err(14670):    at com.wbpro.flood.Test_home$PullToRefreshListViewSampleAdapter.getView(Test_home.java:437)
01-02 11:15:40.085: W/System.err(14670):    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
```

And i`m using the Custom widget for list view

```
 <com.example.pul.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_listview"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white" />
```

This is the custom class

public class PullToRefreshListView extends ListView {

```
private static final float PULL_RESISTANCE = 1.7f;
private static final int BOUNCE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 700;
private static final int BOUNCE_ANIMATION_DELAY = 100;
private static final float BOUNCE_OVERSHOOT_TENSION = 1.4f;
private static final int ROTATE_ARROW_ANIMATION_DURATION = 250;

private static enum State {
    PULL_TO_REFRESH, RELEASE_TO_REFRESH, REFRESHING
}

/**
 * Interface to implement when you want to get notified of 'pull to refresh'
 * events. Call setOnRefreshListener(..) to activate an OnRefreshListener.
 */
public interface OnRefreshListener {

    /**
     * Method to be called when a refresh is requested
     */
    public void onRefresh();
}

private static int measuredHeaderHeight;

private boolean scrollbarEnabled;
private boolean bounceBackHeader;
private boolean lockScrollWhileRefreshing;
private boolean showLastUpdatedText;
private String pullToRefreshText;
private String releaseToRefreshText;
private String refreshingText;
private String lastUpdatedText;
private SimpleDateFormat lastUpdatedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd/MM HH:mm");

private float previousY;
private int headerPadding;
private boolean hasResetHeader;
private long lastUpdated = -1;
private State state;
private LinearLayout headerContainer;
private RelativeLayout header;
private RotateAnimation flipAnimation;
private RotateAnimation reverseFlipAnimation;
private ImageView image;
private ProgressBar spinner;
private TextView text;
private TextView lastUpdatedTextView;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
private OnItemLongClickListener onItemLongClickListener;
private OnRefreshListener onRefreshListener;

private float mScrollStartY;
private final int IDLE_DISTANCE = 5;

public PullToRefreshListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public PullToRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public PullToRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

@Override
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@Override
public void setOnItemLongClickListener(
        OnItemLongClickListener onItemLongClickListener) {
    this.onItemLongClickListener = onItemLongClickListener;
}

/**
 * Activate an OnRefreshListener to get notified on 'pull to refresh'
 * events.
 * 
 * @param onRefreshListener
 *            The OnRefreshListener to get notified
 */
public void setOnRefreshListener(OnRefreshListener onRefreshListener) {
    this.onRefreshListener = onRefreshListener;
}

/**
 * @return If the list is in 'Refreshing' state
 */
public boolean isRefreshing() {
    return state == State.REFRESHING;
}

/**
 * Default is false. When lockScrollWhileRefreshing is set to true, the list
 * cannot scroll when in 'refreshing' mode. It's 'locked' on refreshing.
 * 
 * @param lockScrollWhileRefreshing
 */
public void setLockScrollWhileRefreshing(boolean lockScrollWhileRefreshing) {
    this.lockScrollWhileRefreshing = lockScrollWhileRefreshing;
}

/**
 * Default is false. Show the last-updated date/time in the 'Pull ro
 * Refresh' header. See 'setLastUpdatedDateFormat' to set the date/time
 * formatting.
 * 
 * @param showLastUpdatedText
 */
public void setShowLastUpdatedText(boolean showLastUpdatedText) {
    this.showLastUpdatedText = showLastUpdatedText;
    if (!showLastUpdatedText)
        lastUpdatedTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

/**
 * Default: "dd/MM HH:mm". Set the format in which the last-updated
 * date/time is shown. Meaningless if 'showLastUpdatedText == false
 * (default)'. See 'setShowLastUpdatedText'.
 * 
 * @param lastUpdatedDateFormat
 */
public void setLastUpdatedDateFormat(SimpleDateFormat lastUpdatedDateFormat) {
    this.lastUpdatedDateFormat = lastUpdatedDateFormat;
}

/**
 * Explicitly set the state to refreshing. This is useful when you want to
 * show the spinner and 'Refreshing' text when the refresh was not triggered
 * by 'pull to refresh', for example on start.
 */
public void setRefreshing() {
    state = State.REFRESHING;
    scrollTo(0, 0);
    setUiRefreshing();
    setHeaderPadding(0);
}

/**
 * Set the state back to 'pull to refresh'. Call this method when refreshing
 * the data is finished.
 */
public void onRefreshComplete() {
    state = State.PULL_TO_REFRESH;
    resetHeader();
    lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

/**
 * Change the label text on state 'Pull to Refresh'
 * 
 * @param pullToRefreshText
 *            Text
 */
public void setTextPullToRefresh(String pullToRefreshText) {
    this.pullToRefreshText = pullToRefreshText;
    if (state == State.PULL_TO_REFRESH) {
        text.setText(pullToRefreshText);
    }
}

/**
 * Change the label text on state 'Release to Refresh'
 * 
 * @param releaseToRefreshText
 *            Text
 */
public void setTextReleaseToRefresh(String releaseToRefreshText) {
    this.releaseToRefreshText = releaseToRefreshText;
    if (state == State.RELEASE_TO_REFRESH) {
        text.setText(releaseToRefreshText);
    }
}

/**
 * Change the label text on state 'Refreshing'
 * 
 * @param refreshingText
 *            Text
 */
public void setTextRefreshing(String refreshingText) {
    this.refreshingText = refreshingText;
    if (state == State.REFRESHING) {
        text.setText(refreshingText);
    }
}

private void init() {
    setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

    headerContainer = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.ptr_header, null);
    header = (RelativeLayout) headerContainer
            .findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_header);
    text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_text);
    lastUpdatedTextView = (TextView) header
            .findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_last_updated);
    image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_image);
    spinner = (ProgressBar) header.findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_spinner);

    pullToRefreshText = getContext()
            .getString(R.string.ptr_pull_to_refresh);
    releaseToRefreshText = getContext().getString(
            R.string.ptr_release_to_refresh);
    refreshingText = getContext().getString(R.string.ptr_refreshing);
    lastUpdatedText = getContext().getString(R.string.ptr_last_updated);

    flipAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, -180,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    flipAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    flipAnimation.setDuration(ROTATE_ARROW_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    flipAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    reverseFlipAnimation = new RotateAnimation(-180, 0,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    reverseFlipAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    reverseFlipAnimation.setDuration(ROTATE_ARROW_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    reverseFlipAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    addHeaderView(headerContainer);
    setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);
    scrollbarEnabled = isVerticalScrollBarEnabled();

    ViewTreeObserver vto = header.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new PTROnGlobalLayoutListener());

    super.setOnItemClickListener(new PTROnItemClickListener());
    super.setOnItemLongClickListener(new PTROnItemLongClickListener());
}

private void setHeaderPadding(int padding) {
    headerPadding = padding;

    MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) header
            .getLayoutParams();
    mlp.setMargins(0, Math.round(padding), 0, 0);
    header.setLayoutParams(mlp);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (lockScrollWhileRefreshing
            && (state == State.REFRESHING || getAnimation() != null
                    && !getAnimation().hasEnded())) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
            previousY = event.getY();
        } else {
            previousY = -1;
        }

        // Remember where have we started
        mScrollStartY = event.getY();

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (previousY != -1
                && (state == State.RELEASE_TO_REFRESH || getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0)) {
            switch (state) {
            case RELEASE_TO_REFRESH:
                setState(State.REFRESHING);
                bounceBackHeader();

                break;

            case PULL_TO_REFRESH:
                resetHeader();
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (previousY != -1 && getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0
                && Math.abs(mScrollStartY - event.getY()) > IDLE_DISTANCE) {
            float y = event.getY();
            float diff = y - previousY;
            if (diff > 0)
                diff /= PULL_RESISTANCE;
            previousY = y;

            int newHeaderPadding = Math.max(
                    Math.round(headerPadding + diff), -header.getHeight());

            if (newHeaderPadding != headerPadding
                    && state != State.REFRESHING) {
                setHeaderPadding(newHeaderPadding);

                if (state == State.PULL_TO_REFRESH && headerPadding > 0) {
                    setState(State.RELEASE_TO_REFRESH);

                    image.clearAnimation();
                    image.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
                } else if (state == State.RELEASE_TO_REFRESH
                        && headerPadding < 0) {
                    setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);

                    image.clearAnimation();
                    image.startAnimation(reverseFlipAnimation);
                }
            }
        }

        break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private void bounceBackHeader() {
    int yTranslate = state == State.REFRESHING ? header.getHeight()
            - headerContainer.getHeight() : -headerContainer.getHeight()
            - headerContainer.getTop() + getPaddingTop();
    ;

    TranslateAnimation bounceAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE,
            yTranslate);

    bounceAnimation.setDuration(BOUNCE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    bounceAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
    bounceAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
    bounceAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
    bounceAnimation.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(
            BOUNCE_OVERSHOOT_TENSION));
    bounceAnimation.setAnimationListener(new HeaderAnimationListener(
            yTranslate));

    startAnimation(bounceAnimation);
}

private void resetHeader() {
    if (getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0) {
        setHeaderPadding(-header.getHeight());
        setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);
        return;
    }

    if (getAnimation() != null && !getAnimation().hasEnded()) {
        bounceBackHeader = true;
    } else {
        bounceBackHeader();
    }
}

private void setUiRefreshing() {
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    image.clearAnimation();
    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    text.setText(refreshingText);
}

private void setState(State state) {
    this.state = state;
    switch (state) {
    case PULL_TO_REFRESH:
        spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        text.setText(pullToRefreshText);

        if (showLastUpdatedText && lastUpdated != -1) {
            lastUpdatedTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lastUpdatedTextView.setText(String.format(lastUpdatedText,
                    lastUpdatedDateFormat.format(new Date(lastUpdated))));
        }

        break;

    case RELEASE_TO_REFRESH:
        spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        text.setText(releaseToRefreshText);
        break;

    case REFRESHING:
        setUiRefreshing();

        lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (onRefreshListener == null) {
            setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);
        } else {
            onRefreshListener.onRefresh();
        }

        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

    if (!hasResetHeader) {
        if (measuredHeaderHeight > 0 && state != State.REFRESHING) {
            setHeaderPadding(-measuredHeaderHeight);
        }

        hasResetHeader = true;
    }
}

private class HeaderAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {

    private int height, translation;
    private State stateAtAnimationStart;

    public HeaderAnimationListener(int translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        stateAtAnimationStart = state;

        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams();
        height = lp.height;
        lp.height = getHeight() - translation;
        setLayoutParams(lp);

        if (scrollbarEnabled) {
            setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        setHeaderPadding(stateAtAnimationStart == State.REFRESHING ? 0
                : -measuredHeaderHeight - headerContainer.getTop());
        setSelection(0);

        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = height;
        setLayoutParams(lp);

        if (scrollbarEnabled) {
            setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        }

        if (bounceBackHeader) {
            bounceBackHeader = false;

            postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    resetHeader();
                }
            }, BOUNCE_ANIMATION_DELAY);
        } else if (stateAtAnimationStart != State.REFRESHING) {
            setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
}

private class PTROnGlobalLayoutListener implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int initialHeaderHeight = header.getHeight();

        if (initialHeaderHeight > 0) {
            measuredHeaderHeight = initialHeaderHeight;

            if (measuredHeaderHeight > 0 && state != State.REFRESHING) {
                setHeaderPadding(-measuredHeaderHeight);
                requestLayout();
            }
        }

        getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
}

private class PTROnItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        hasResetHeader = false;

        if (onItemClickListener != null && state == State.PULL_TO_REFRESH) {
            // Passing up onItemClick. Correct position with the number of
            // header views
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(adapterView, view, position
                    - getHeaderViewsCount(), id);
        }
    }
}

private class PTROnItemLongClickListener implements OnItemLongClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        hasResetHeader = false;

        if (onItemLongClickListener != null
                && state == State.PULL_TO_REFRESH) {
            // Passing up onItemLongClick. Correct position with the number
            // of header views
            return onItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(adapterView,
                    view, position - getHeaderViewsCount(), id);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

}

i had populated the data fine. but the problem is when is refresh the adaptor.

```
listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                 adapter.loadData();
                listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listView.onRefreshComplete();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });



ArrayList<Claim_list> claim_list_adaptor = Claim_list.getItems("0", Test_home.this);
```

Comment: what is exactly line 437 ? Is it : final Claim_list claim_option = claim_list_adaptor.get(position); ?

Comment: Show the code of how your are refershing the ListView on Pull request ?

Comment: holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); this is the 437 th code

Comment: @GrIsHu Im Using Custom Listview ;have a triger on refresh then i update the adaptor and  last notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Your problem java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: @user2732376 Show your java file code

Comment: How you have initialized `listView` ?

Comment: private PullToRefreshListView listView;

Comment: listView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.claim_list);

Comment: @user2732376 Make sure your `PullToRefereshListView` class resides inside the `com.example.pul` package only.

Comment: yes it is working properly for me the problem is while im refreshinh the adptor

Comment: Try removing the Runnable code while refereshing the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `else` to get the tag of your views and remove the code of setting the tags again.

Try to change the code of your `getView()` method as below:

```
        if (convertView == null) {
            // LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
            // getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_list, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.claim_list_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.claim_list_layout);
            holder.claimnumb = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.claimnumb);
            holder.insuerdname = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.insuerdname);

            holder.claimaddress = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.claimaddress);
            holder.btn_start = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
         {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
          }

        final Claim_list claim_option = claim_list_adaptor.get(position);

        holder1.claimnumb.setText(claim_option.getClaimNumber());
        holder1.insuerdname.setText(claim_option.getInsuredName());
        holder1.claimaddress.setText(claim_option.getPropertyAddress());



        holder1.btn_start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (position == 0 && isoncreate) {
            isoncreate = false;
            holder1.claim_list_layout
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.claim_list_active);
            holder1.btn_start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            beanclass.setClaim_info_header("Claim: "
                    + claim_option.getClaimNumber() + " / "
                    + claim_option.getInsuredName());
            TV_claiminfo.setText(beanclass.getClaim_info_header());
        } else {
            holder1.claim_list_layout
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.claim_list_inactive);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: 01-02 18:17:52.683: W/dalvikvm(6675): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41dc12a0)
01-02 18:17:52.693: W/System.err(6675): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.wbpro.da.Claim_list cannot be cast to com.wbpro.flood.Test_home$PullToRefreshListViewSampleAdapter$ViewHolder
01-02 18:17:52.693: W/System.err(6675):  at com.wbpro.flood.Test_home$PullToRefreshListViewSampleAdapter.getView(Test_home.java:437)

Comment: @user2732376 Please show what is `Claim_list claim_option` and what is  `claim_list_adaptor`.

Comment: claim_option is the object of the class Claim_list it holds the data for the listview claim_list_adaptor is the ArrayList of the class Claim_list ArrayList<Claim_list>

Comment: Why are you trying to get the position this way ? Try out this way `final Claim_list.claim_list_adaptor.get(position);`

Comment: The error is occurring only because of this as you are assigning  the Value of arraylist to the Instance of the class. Which will obviously leads to Class cast exception only.

Comment: @GrlsHu that is becoz i`m populating the values from database so this is dynamic values that is Y im using this way and thats works for me

Comment: But you can not assign the ArrayList Value to directly the instance of the Class.

Comment: @GrlsHU please try it without refresh it work perfect.
 final Claim_list claim_option = claim_list_adaptor.get(position);
here we get each row respective to each row

Comment: Here What i need is to update the claim_list_adaptor which is a ArrayList<Claim_list> and update the listview please help :(

Comment: While i debuged the program the postion in getview method is repeating i mean it is repeating from the begining 0,1,2,3 ....

Comment: That is coming because the getView behavior is like that.

Comment: the error is occuring at 
holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

becoz of if view of Position 1 is already created but it is again called and den execute the above code get class exception :(

Comment: Hi @GrlsHs What to do wen the convertView is not null ? in the getview method?

Comment: when the convertedview not null  holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); is executed it is making the exception

Comment: Have you kept it in the else condition ?

Comment: @GrlsHU Thank You So much my error was "I was using the layout id of the outter most layout i removed that and add another layout inside of that and it works perfect :) :)

Comment: You mean you were getting in `TV_claiminfo.setText(beanclass.getClaim_info_header());` line ? @user2732376

Comment: no no i was using the Linear layout of the Row xml to change the background of each row that was the error

Answer (score 0):

```
holder1.claimnumb.setTag(claim_option);
            holder1.insuerdname.setTag(claim_option);
            holder1.claimaddress.setTag(claim_option);
            holder1.claim_list_layout.setTag(claim_option);
            holder1.btn_start.setTag(claim_option);
```

These statements are creating problem for Class-cast Exception , you should not cast the holder again. Use a single reference for holder.

Use this code

```
if (convertView == null) {
            // LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
            // getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_list, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.claim_list_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.claim_list_layout);
            holder.claimnumb = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.claimnumb);
            holder.insuerdname = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.insuerdname);

            holder.claimaddress = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.claimaddress);
            holder.btn_start = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
         {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
          }

        final Claim_list claim_option = claim_list_adaptor.get(position);

        holder.claimnumb.setText(claim_option.getClaimNumber());
        holder.insuerdname.setText(claim_option.getInsuredName());
        holder.claimaddress.setText(claim_option.getPropertyAddress());



        holder.btn_start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (position == 0 && isoncreate) {
            isoncreate = false;
            holder.claim_list_layout
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.claim_list_active);
            holder.btn_start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            beanclass.setClaim_info_header("Claim: "
                    + claim_option.getClaimNumber() + " / "
                    + claim_option.getInsuredName());
            TV_claiminfo.setText(beanclass.getClaim_info_header());
        } else {
            holder.claim_list_layout
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.claim_list_inactive);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

And to refresh just take updated data on your array list and call notifyDataSetchanged method of your adapter. Make sure dont use new instance of your adapter.

Comment: i have changed holder1 to holder